"Expected an object and got a string instead" issue with ask_chatgpt in R
I'm trying to run the ask_chatgpt function through multiple lines in R. A basic example:
Loading the basic information, excluding the API:
### load current ChatGPT package: https://github.com/jcrodriguez1989/chatgpt
install.packages("chatgpt")
library(chatgpt)

### load GPT API
Sys.setenv(OPENAI_API_KEY = "XXX")

Separate questions:
### first question
cat(ask_chatgpt("Is Arkansas in the United States?"))


Yes, Arkansas is a state in the United States. It is located in the southern region of the country.

### second question
cat(ask_chatgpt("Is Arkansas in India?"))


No, Arkansas is not in India. Arkansas is a state in the United States, while India is a country located in South Asia. They are two separate and distinct geographical locations.

But if, separately, I attempt to run the questions through dplyr::mutate, I get the following error message:
### write into dataframe
test <- data.frame(x = c("Is Arkansas in the United States?", "Is Arkansas in India?"))

### ask_chatgpt
test <- test %>%
  mutate(y = cat(ask_chatgpt(x)))


Error in `mutate()`: ! Problem while computing `y = ask_chatgpt(x)`. Caused by error in `gpt_get_completions()`: ! list(message = "Invalid type for 'messages[13].content[0]': expected an object, but got a string instead.", type = "invalid_request_error", param = "messages[13].content[0]", code = "invalid_type") Backtrace:   1. test %>% mutate(y = ask_chatgpt(x))   7. chatgpt::ask_chatgpt(x)  19. chatgpt:::gpt_get_completions(question, messages = chat_session_messages)  20. base::stop(content(post_res))

How can I fix this? I'm not sure I see an obvious solution in the documentation. Thanks!

Try not using cat, a function with no return value (invisible NULL), see help("cat"). What your mutate is doing is to call ChatGPT, get an answer, pass it on to cat and assign the return value of cat to y.

Have you tried the {elmer} package or the {mall} package?

The outputs of the cat() are not objects that R can further process. If you want to ask multiple questions and save the answers, try sapply.
test <- data.frame(
  x = c("Is Arkansas in the United States?", "Is Arkansas in India?")
)

test$y <- sapply(test$x, ask_chatgpt)


That worked, thanks! Joke's on me for over-relying on dplyr.
